# How to query data by some conditions

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a dataset, now I want to find the data(point) which have the value of "country" is "AU", and show them on the map,

how to express the variable in Mapbox JS GL code?

this is my code, but it is a filter method, I know it's wrong, how to express a condition not filter it?

```
var myFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures('my_layer'
                filter: ["==", "country", "AU"]
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter source features like this:

```
const myFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures(
  "points",
  {
    filter: ["==", ["get", "title"], "Mapbox SF"]
  }
);
```

Here, "title" is the property name and "Mapbox SF" is the property value.

Here's a codepen to demonstrate this: https://codepen.io/manishraj/pen/jONQQgo